# upgrading from Postgresql 9.1 to 9.3 on Ubuntu using Londiste

Tags: postgresql

I am undertaking a project to upgrade our Postgresql production database from 9.1 to 9.3 using Londiste.

The reason I choose Londiste is to avoid substantial downtime from restoring the dump file or using pg_upgrade.

I have to upgrade 5 interconnected instances on separate servers at the same time. And, I am testing it on our test db servers.

From this website, I know that someone has used Londiste to upgrade to Postgres higher version before.

So, I would appreciate if anyone can share his/her experience here.

Thanks

Comment: Look the answer of MatheusOl **http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/60465/upgrading-from-postgres-9-1-to-9-3-on-ubuntu-server**