# Migrating PostgreSQL 9.1 database to Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, postgresql-9.1, ubuntu

I want to migrate a database from PostgreSQL 9.1 installed on an old Debian system to Ubuntu 14.04. The database is making use of triggers and it is a requirement that the triggers be migrated as well, but without having the triggers executed on every row as it is migrated to the new database causing the new database to contain a garbled version of the original data.

The PostgreSQL version in the Ubuntu 14.04 repository is 9.3.

**Is there any way I can convert the data from `/var/lib/postgresql/9.1` on the old system to be usable on PostgreSQL 9.3?**

*What I have tried so far*

I found an [older answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/60541/47085) on how to migrate from 9.1 to 9.3. But I did not have much luck using it.

Using `pg_dump` will as far as I understand require the old database to be running as the data is being dumped, which could lead to updates written during the dump to be missing from the new database.

Using `pg_upgrade` requires both PostgreSQL versions to be installed simultaneously. But 9.1 is not available in the Ubuntu 14.04 repositories. I considered replicating the old system into a chroot on the new machine, but I don't know if that will play well with how `pg_upgrade` will create hardlinks.

There is another hurdle which so far prevented me from testing `pg_upgrade`. When I try to run `pg_upgrade` I am told that the command is in the `postgres-xc` package which is not installed.

If I try to install `postgres-xc` it tells me that `postgres-xc` depends on `postgres-xc-client`.

If I try installing `postgres-xc-client` I am told that doing so will uninstall posgres-9.3. So it appears it is not even possible to have `pg_upgrade` and PostgreSQL 9.3 installed at the same time.

Comment: @joanolo It very clearly told me that I needed `postgres-xc`. I will investigate further why it is telling me that I need `postgres-xc`.

Comment: Another approach:

pg_dump needs the old database to be running; but most probably you should be able to restrict connections to "just the one that is doing the dump". You might be able to do it in your app. If not, most probably can be done by modifying pg_hba.conf; setting all access methods to "reject" except for one single privileged local user [let's call it pg_dump_privileged_user] you should have created beforehand for the purpose of using pg_dump.

Comment: I think pg_upgrade should be an executable located where all the PostgreSQL executables are located. So, you may check there. In any case, I don't think it's safe to use it to transfer data between two different OSs. At least, I don't think this was part of the original purpose, and I am not sure the data is stored in a way that is binary compatible between OSs.

Comment: @joanolo Turns out there is a `/usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/bin/pg_upgrade` but it is not in my `PATH` which is why it couldn't find it. I guess the `postgres-xc` contains a different `pg_upgrade` command which would be in a directory in my current `PATH`. So it seems that error message was misleading. Whether that fully solves my problem remains to be seen.

Comment: @joanolo If the database could be set in read only mode while performing the dump, that might be ideal. I don't know if there is such a thing as a read only mode for PostgreSQL.

Comment: @joanolo Calling Debian and Ubuntu two different OS may be an exaggeration in this context. As far as I can tell there is a larger difference between different versions of the same distribution than there is between similar versions of the same distribution.

Comment: WRT to "readonly mode", it seems there is a possibility. Check for default_transaction_read_only at https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/runtime-config-client.html, and check also https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/5fe0d78bda51d7176940fb8e78739b54@biglumber.com  

(I've never used this feature myself... I guess I would really make some trials to make sure you cannot UPDATE or INSERT anything).

Debian and Ubuntu: they may be similarly based, but you can have  lots of little diffs. I think pg_upgrade was thought for upgrading between 2 versions of DB within same machine.

Comment: @joanolo Looks like using `pg_dump` and running the output through `psql` does the right thing with respect to triggers. And it is not as slow as the other answer had me thinking. Now I just need to figure out whether I would rather trust a binary or a textual dump. And I need to verify that it correctly handles all the unusual characters that the users have entered.

Comment: @joanolo `default_transaction_read_only` appears to work. But I do wonder whether transactions started before the change might still be committing changes after a reload. Might be safer to do a full restart of the database and not just a reload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message from the `command-not-found` package telling me I needed to install `postgres-xc` turned out to be misleading. In fact `pg_upgrade` is part of the default install but it is not in the default `PATH` rather it is located in `/usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/bin/pg_upgrade`.

Because `pg_upgrade` was not in `PATH` a search through available packages was performed and the `postgres-xc` package happens to have a `/usr/bin/pg_upgrade` executable. That was however not the `pg_upgrade` I was looking for.

Alas `pg_upgrade` would not work unless I was able to bring up a PostgreSQL instance serving the files in `/var/lib/postgresql/9.1` which I wasn't able to do with the packages available in Ubuntu 14.04 repositories.

So I concluded that the answer to my question most likely was: **No, converting the files in /var/lib/postgresql/9.1 is not possible using software from the Ubuntu 14.04 repository.**

What I did in the end was to use `pg_dump` on the Debian system where the database originated. My concern about changes being made while `pg_dump` was running were addressed by setting `default_transaction_read_only` in `/etc/postgresql/9.1/main/postgresql.conf`. To ensure that no currently running transaction would commit after I started `pg_dump`, I restarted PostgreSQL between enabling `default_transaction_read_only` and starting `pg_dump`.

This approach had the added benefit of at least having the system keep running in read-only mode while the migration was ongoing, thus minimising the user visible downtime.

Before I started this manoeuvre I verified the process using the output of a `pg_dump` command performed on the running database.

In particular I verified that:

- Database triggers were migrated correctly.
- Unusual unicode characters in the data were migrated correctly.

I decided to use the textual output from `pg_dump` to be imported by using `psql` rather than the binary output format, because that allowed me to easily perform a few manual sanity checks on the file being migrated between the two databases.